Calculating textwidth of Combobox text in Firemonkey
Using Delphi 12.1 Firemonkey.
Why does this give an access violation due to combobox1.canvas being nil?
TextWidth := combobox1.Canvas.TextWidth('some text');

Is there a correct way to know how much width (in pixels) TCombobox text takes up based on existing set font for the combobox?

The way you have written it is correct and should work. There must be some more circumstance that makes it not work.

When/where are you trying to execute this code?

oh, I think I found the issue.  The combobox is on a TFrame that is created dynamically. for some reason, the combbox.canvas is nil in this case.  Code works ok on a normal form. I'll check if the TFrame has a parent that is a form - maybe that is the issue.

ok the parent of the TFrame that contains the TCombobox has parent=nil. Just curious why it results in this error due to this?

Is the frame and its control even created at the time you execute your code?

yes, of course. other thnings work fine.

Thanks for all the replies. I found the problem. will post in an answer.

As the TFrame is dynamically created at run time, it runs some code to calculate the TextWidth.  However, at this time, the parent of frame is not assigned yet. Hence, for some reason, if the TFrame has no parent (probably has to be a visual control), its canvas property is nil. I have moved the code to calculate the TextWidth away from the Create section.
Lesson: TFrame seems to depend on a parent for its canvas property, and any access to canvas of any objects on TFrame should not be done in Create.

Just to be ideally useful for others later: either the question or answer should contain the fact that the combobox is on a TFrame and that the parent of that TFrame has parent=nil. This fact is right now only in the comments to the question.
